# Why does my loop increment 1 over the value needed?

Tags: java, loops, increment

This is my first CS class ever, and I'm trying to learn everything the best that can. In this loop I am trying to find valid mastercard numbers using Luhn's formula. The program works, but it's been bugging me that my final for loop outputs 1 number over the correct value, unless I subtract 1 from z after the loop finishes iterating. For example: if the sum = 56 , then z would = 5 , when the correct answer would be 4. How can I fix this going forward?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
public class MCGenerator {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.print("How many Mastercard numbers would you like to generate? ");
        int quantity = scnr.nextInt();
        int x;
        int use;
        int range;
        int appendI;
        Long appendL;
        String firstDigits;
        String append;
        String preliminary;
        int y;
        int c;
        int sum;
        int z;
        int findDigit;
        String lastNum;
        String cardNumber;

        System.out.println("\nHere you go, have fun: ");

        for(x = 0; x < quantity; x++ ) {
             use = rand.nextInt(2 - 1 + 1) +1;

            if(use  == 1) {
                range = rand.nextInt(55 - 51 + 1) + 51;
            }
            else {
                range = rand.nextInt(272099 - 222100 +1) + 222100;
            }

            if(range < 56) {
                appendL = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1000000000000L, 10000000000000L);
    
                append = String.valueOf(appendL);
            }
            else {
                appendI = rand.nextInt(999999999 - 100000000 + 1) + 100000000;
                append = String.valueOf(appendI);
            }
    
            firstDigits = String.valueOf(range);
            preliminary = firstDigits + append;

    
            for(y = 0, sum = 0; y < 15; y++ ) {
                c = preliminary.charAt(y) - '0';
                if(y % 2 == 0){
                    c *= 2;
                }   
                if(c > 9) {
                    c -= 9; 
                }   
                sum += c;
            }

            for(z = 0, findDigit = sum; findDigit > 0; z++){
                findDigit = sum + z;
                findDigit %= 10;
            }
            z -= 1;

            lastNum = String.valueOf(z);
            cardNumber = preliminary + lastNum;
            System.out.println(cardNumber);
    
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop iterates a final time when findDigit is 10. You could just put your modulo operation in your for loop condition. `findDigit % 10 > 0;` Then the loop will break before incrementing z that final time.

Comment: Because for `for` loops it first runs the initialization of the loop and then runs the condition, then the body, then the increment, then the condition, then the body, then the increment, then the condition, ..... And `z` will be incremented to 5 at some point and only then will the next condition check fail while having `z` at the first "invalid" value.

Comment: However, your loop really only seems to find the difference between sum and the ceiling 10*n number, so you could just do `z = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;` and skip the loop entirely.

Comment: David thank you! The condition you gave me gives me the wrong output, sometimes adding an extra 0 on the end of a number occasionally. However the equation you provided for z does the trick. This lab is about loops, perhaps I was over thinking it a bit. I'm still a little confused about the for loops I guess because I have another program that also runs 1 over. But not all of my for loops do, and I fell like I do them the same way, so I guess I'm a little confused... any tips for the more complicated for loops?